# Autostarting bond with DHCP and eth in /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, bonding

As the title says, I'm getting conflicts when autostarting both a bond and a regular connection when using DHCP. I started a Question at ServerFault (link below), and they pointed out some conflicts, but I think it is solvable with the correct Unix configuration and commands.

Basically when autostarting both, the bond0 specifies the slave and the eth0 (enp0s25) also specifies the master. I have tried running network.service without either of those to disentangle them, but it hangs, regardless of which autostart line comes first in the config file below.

Most working examples use static network addresses. As I ended up bolding in the ServerFault question, the bonding does work if I pull one up manually after the other is autostarted. But is there a way to have the bonding load without intervention on system startup? While still using DHCP?

I put a detailed description of my troubleshooting steps at this link, but it may be more confusing than someone just looking at my config file below. And knowing how to have the config file autostart both the bond and connection independently, but still be able to turn on the bonding.. maybe I just need a script to do that, but I wanted to check if there is a 'correct' way of doing this with the config file alone. And if not, point out the conflict for what seems to be should be a simple operation of auto-starting the bond and connection, at the very least, and then connecting them into the master-slave connection (not a huge fan of that choice of terminology btw, but understand its conventional use)? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

If I need to start the bond0 in manual instead of dhcp, that makes sense, but then how do I get bond0 to ask for an IP address once the bonding is finished. ..yes, I tried again to autostart the bond0 with and without enp0s25 being manual or dhcp, and with or without the bond-master line, and with or without the bond-slaves detail, but none work, just hangs on "DHCPDISCOVER on bond0". This may be the conflict between layer 2 and layer 3 as mentioned in my other question, but is there no way to control layer 3 DHCP from the shell?

https://serverfault.com/questions/1082039/configuring-connection-bonding-chicken-and-egg

```
auto enp0s25  
iface enp0s25 inet dhcp
#iface enp0s25 inet manual
#   bond-master bond0

#auto bond0
iface bond0 inet dhcp
    up ifenslave bond0 enp0s25
    down ifenslave -d bond0 enp0s25  
bond-mode balance-rr
bond-miimon 100
#bond-slaves enp0s25 
bond-slaves none
```

Comment: This is a *cross-post* from https://serverfault.com/questions/1082039/configuring-connection-bonding-chicken-and-egg . You already had an answer this is impossible because the tool you chose for the problem is incorrect, but appear to not listen to any explanation. Cross-posting is strongly discouraged and nobody will help you here too. Refusal won't help too; better listen to what experienced admins say.

Comment: To be more thorough , you must not set an IP address on a slave interface. For bonding, you must not enslave an UP interface (which you are doing in the up command with ifenslave). Also ifenslave is a deprecated command that should be replaced with ip link. All this won't change the fact that bonding can't be done across two ISPs.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the autostarting problem was solved by using the `teamd` utility, described in the link below.

Load balancing multiple NICs on single machine presenting a virtual IP
https://serverfault.com/questions/953328/load-balancing-multiple-nics-on-single-machine-presenting-a-virtual-ip

The question of how to combine networks for increased speed like Speedify is still open. I've added some ideas on the ServerFault question.